# Profile Bug - Answers Title Now Displays #~TotalAnswers# Answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, meta

There appears to be a new bug on the Meta site. This doesn't happen on SO.

In the profile page under the Summary tab, the Answers section title is displayed as:

> (count) #~TotalAnswers# Answers

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Answers Title]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What, you don't have pound-tilde-TotalAnswers?

Sorry about that, bug in changing some view re-writing I'm doing there.  It was fixed in the latest deploy, and never got to any site but MSO.

Comment: Actually, according to the screen shot, I have 7. :) Thanks, for the fix, it looks better now!

Comment: Ha interesting, so MSO is the testbed.