# Recommend Close -> Duplicates -> Search -> #Count# results

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dialog

[image: #Count# results (top 30 shown)]

This may be related to [Profile Bug - Answers Title Now Displays #~TotalAnswers# Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190226/profile-bug-answers-title-now-displays-totalanswers-answers), but its only answer claims that the buggy build never got past Meta, whereas I encountered this in the Low Quality Posts queue on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different, but obviously similar, bug to that one.

This was fixed in the latest build.