# Placeholders in mobile search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile-web

When searching in a mobile browser (using the mobile theme), each **question** title in the search result is followed by this text:

```
("#Score# votes, #AnswerCount# answers)
```

The `"` looks suspicious. **Answers** on the same page are fine, having, e.g., `(3 votes)`. I found this on SO, MSO and on German.SE.

See also this similar issue: [Recommend Close -> Duplicates -> Search -> #Count# results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190246)

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190226/profile-bug-answers-title-now-displays-totalanswers-answers). (There seem to be a lot of #SubstitutionBugs# today.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be fixed as soon as the next build rolls out.

Comment: Fixed now, as far as I can see.